# App crashes when scrolling and pressing cancel on search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

<strike>My app uses pagination in order to display the data in the table. At every 5 recipes, I make a new request with Alamofire to get the data and display it in the cells. I also have a search bar which uses the same tableView to display the searched data in (and also uses pagination).</strike>

When I press the cancel button, the most recent recipes from the server will be displayed.

The problem is that if I am scrolling  <strike>between two 'pages'</strike>  and press the cancel button, the app would crash.

My guess is that this happens because the app will try to populate the cell at an index corresponding to a search result cell (which will be higher than the results from the first list).

The recipes from the search results and the ones from the main list are the same because it is a mock server (you can look at the console to better understand what requests are being made).
**Video**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGGZBZtY-J4&spfreload=10

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! RecipeTableViewCell

    if searchController.isActive == false {
        cell.loadRecipePreview(recipe: recipes[indexPath.row])
        if indexPath.row == recipes.count - 1 {
            recipeRequest()
        }
    }
    else {
        cell.loadRecipePreview(recipe: searchRecipes[indexPath.row])
        if indexPath.row == searchRecipes.count - 1 {
            recipeSearchRequest()
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

**Edit:** I think that the problem doesn't have anything to do with pagination, because this also happens when not scrolling between two pages.

Comment: Where do you set "searchController.isActive" before or after you reload your table??

Answer (score 0):

How many recipes are in your array `recipes[]`? You are using an array index which is greater than the array size. Arrays are "zero-based", i.e if array has a total of 6 items, valid array indexes are 0...5. If you attempt to access `recipes[7]` you will get that "fatal: index out of range error" you are seeing in your log.

Make sure the number of rows correspond to the number of recipes in the array.

Comment: There will be 0 everytime I press cancel because I want to update with the most recent recipes and immediately after that I start populating it, so there will be 5. As a side note, I think that the problem doesn't have anything to do with pagination, because this also happens when not scrolling between two pages.

Comment: is func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int called again after the cancel button? if not you will get the number of searchrecipes. You may need to reload the table after cancelling the search.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by modfiying the first if with `if searchController.isActive == false && indexPath.row < recipes.count && recipes.count != 0` altough I am not sure that this is the best way to do it. The question is still open.